# Rails server takes minutes to display first page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When starting up the rails server, the first web page display takes minutes.  From the RAILS Log - notice the jump from minute 55 to 57 when displaying application.html:

```
2018-10-11T14:55:30.838+02:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] [0e7498c2-d398-4a9a-bdac-427eec662359] Started GET "/" for 81.83.5.163 at 2018-10-11 12:55:30 +0000
2018-10-11T14:55:30.840+02:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] [0e7498c2-d398-4a9a-bdac-427eec662359] Processing by HomeController#index as HTML
2018-10-11T14:55:30.853+02:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] [0e7498c2-d398-4a9a-bdac-427eec662359] Rendering home/index.html.erb within layouts/application
2018-10-11T14:55:30.853+02:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] [0e7498c2-d398-4a9a-bdac-427eec662359] Rendering layouts/application.html.erb
2018-10-11T14:**55**:30.854+02:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] [0e7498c2-d398-4a9a-bdac-427eec662359] Rendered home/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.7ms)
2018-10-11T14:**57**:39.101+02:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] [0e7498c2-d398-4a9a-bdac-427eec662359] Rendered layouts/_menu_website.html.erb (2.2ms)
```

Code in application.html before _menu_website is called:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="<%=asset_url 'apple-touch-icon'%>">
    <link rel="mask-icon" href="<%=asset_url 'safari-pinned-tab.svg'%>" color="#ffc40d">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Reenie+Beanie');</style>
    <style>@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,500');</style>
    <%=stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all"%>
    <%=javascript_include_tag "application"%>
    <%=csrf_meta_tags%>
  </head>

%=stylesheet_link_tag "custom/forms", :media => "all"%>
<%=stylesheet_link_tag "custom/library", :media => "all"%>
<%=stylesheet_link_tag "custom/home", :media => "all"%>
<%=javascript_include_tag "materialize", :media => "all"%>
<%=javascript_include_tag "materialize-form", :media => "all"%>
```

Is there any way to speed this up?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the following settings in my production.rb config file:

```
config.assets.compile
config.assets.debug = false
config.assets.digest = true
```

This initially caused issues with images not being found.

I standardized on using the following rails helpers:
    image_tag
    favicon_link_tag